# Django save image in folder

Tags: python, django, image, matplotlib

I´ve got a piece of code that creates an image using matplotlib in Django and saves it to the root directory. I need to change the folder where matplotlib saves the image to /static/img folder.

```
    if (len(funcion) == 2):
        plotter = plot_regions([
            [(lambda x: (matrizRestricciones[0][2]-matrizRestricciones[0]
            [0]*x)/matrizRestricciones[0][1],True),
            (lambda x: (matrizRestricciones[1][2]-matrizRestricciones[1]
            [0]*x)/matrizRestricciones[1][1],True)]], xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0,10))
        plt.grid()
        plt.savefig("/static/img/imagen.png")
        plt.close()
```

Any idea how to save them there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

# ... your code ...
# ...
 plt.savefig(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static/img/imagen.png'))
```

---

**Note:** From your code, it appears that while you're saving the image you're not giving it a unique name. So, if you create a new image, it will replace the older image. If that is the desired behaviour, ignore this. If not, you can use [`uuid.uuid4`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4) to generate unique names for your images.

Comment: Alternatively, you could write `plt.savefig(settings.STATIC_ROOT,'imgaen.png')`